# Connecting to REST Api and retrieving JSON

Tags: c#, api

I am connecting to an API, but not having any luck retrieving the data in Json. I have different endpoints to use, but cant seem the any to work. I believe /products should give me the entire list but am having no luck.

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //go get the data

            string token = "auth token";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Console.WriteLine("GET");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/products/6");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                RootObject product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();


                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", product.data.id,product.data.name,product.data.sort,product.data.designation_id,product.data.designation_id);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response I am getting in the console on this is:

```
0
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Product class:

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Product data { get; set; }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public object designation_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object alternate_name { get; set; }
        public object description { get; set; }
        public int sort { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
    }
```

The response I get when testing connection with postman is as follows:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 6,
        "designation_id": null,
        "name": "Multirate Fork Springs Kit",
        "alternate_name": null,
        "description": null,
        "sort": 0,
        "created_at": "2016-06-17 20:47:51",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-25 09:40:50"
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to know what exactly happens when you run this code.

Comment: I updated the post with more info including the response I am getting, as well as the class I am using. I also included the Json response when connecting with postman to test connection/credentials.

Comment: The question is closed so I cannot answer. However, you are missing a wrapper class: `public class Wrapper { public Product data { get; set; } }` (notice that the product fields are inside the `data` attribute in the JSON)

Comment: kevin camilo is right, now that youve posted the json, we can see, your product class must be wrapped in `data` you can make a data class with just a Product variable with getter and setter, and then `await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Data>(); `   then access it with data.product

Comment: @Vanethrane I have edited my Product class, but am still unable to get any response. Currently the console line that I should be writing is just returning "0". I was unable to access using data.product, only "product.id,product.name,etc"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto with the wrapper installed, I am still getting no results. main post has been updated to show my class.

Comment: @Kevin You are still using `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();` when it should be `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto success! We are in business. Thank you for the help. I will update OP

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have moved on to attempting to download the full product list, not just one product. The error I am getting is "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[APIapp.RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly." Do I need to change the class again?

Comment: Different data requires different classes I'd need to see the JSON and your attempt to help you however. The exception can be explained as "you have a JSON object and you want to convert it to a c# list instead of an object"

Comment: Also, if the question contains the answer, it's not a question, it's an answer. Please only modify questions to include more details needed for answers, not to include the answers

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ok. JSON is the same as listed above in original post. The API has thousands of products I am attempting to loop through. My current class is listed above.

Comment: So shouldn't you be using `await client.GetAsync("/products");` to get all products rather than only one?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That is what I am currently using with no success. Using this code:  List<RootObject> product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<RootObject>>();

Answer (score 0):

nuget Newtonsoft.Json

and you can do something like this:

```
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

in client, using response

```
Product product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(your response string);
```

this works really well, as long as your product class has all the right attributes you should be good to go!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  The OP's `ReadAsAsync` is basically doing that deserialization already.  There are a handful of places before that point in the code where the process could be failing and that's why the commenter above is asking for further information.

Comment: Updated the original post with more information. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked.